# Module over $R$ isomorphic to $R$ itself

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, module-isomorphism

Let $R$ be an associative ring with unity. I have two questions:

1. If $M$ is a left $R$-module such that $\phi:M\mapsto R$ is an $R$-isomorphism, i.e., $M$ and $R$ are isomorphic as modules, does this imply that $M$ can be given a ring structure? I thought about defining multiplication in $M$ simply as $\cdot:M\times M\mapsto M, m_1\cdot m_2 = \phi^{-1}(\phi(m_1)\phi(m_2))$. I did the calculations and this appears to work and guarantee that $M$ with this product is also an associative ring with unity given by $\phi^{-1}(1_R)$. Is this correct? If so, is this a useful construction?
2. If $R$ is commutative and $M$ is a simple $R$-module, then $M$ must be $R$-isomorphic to $R/I$, where $I$ is a maximal ideal of $R$. Since $I$ is maximal, this means that $R/I$ is a field. Is there a way of giving $M$ a field structure from this $R$-isomorphism? From the previous questions, I believe that if such isomorphism also happened to be an $R/I$-isomorphism, then yes, but is this true in general? And again, is this a useful construction?

Comment: If you have any ring $R$ and set $X$ and a bijection $R\to X$, you can transport the operation from $R$ to $X$ by defining $\phi(r)+\phi(s):=\phi(r+s)$ and $\phi(r)\phi(s):=\phi(rs)$ in $X$. This _forces_ $\phi$ to be a ring isomorphism with the new operations thus defined.  Obviously you can do analogous things with groups, modules etc.  Google "transport of structure."  It is not often useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both cases it is no problem giving the module $M$ a ring (field) structure. As you checked yourself, all ring (field) axioms are true and $\phi$ becomes an isomorphism of rings (fields).

As for usefulness: Usually this is not a very helpful construction. One reason for this is that this ring structure on $M$ is not natural. Unless $1$ is the only unit in $R$ (which is quite a special case) there are multiple isomorphisms $M \to R$ of $R$-modules. Each isomorphism gives a different ring structure on $M$. For example, take the isomorphism $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}, n \mapsto -n$ of $\mathbb{Z}$-modules. The resulting ring structure on $\mathbb{Z}$ is given by the multiplication $(n,m) \mapsto -nm$, which is not the usual multiplication.

The question still left is, if an $R$-module homomorphism of $R/I$-modules is also $R/I$-linear. This is true, as can be easily checked:
$$\phi(a x) = \phi((a+I)x) = (a+I)\phi(x) = a\phi(x).$$